# How can I retrieve an extended property for a Google Calendar event?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, extended-properties

I have several extended properties I've added to various events using PHP. Now I want to retrieve them using Google Apps Script in Google Sheets. I'm able to access the calendar, all events and the standard data elements like this:

```
 var mycal = "... my calendar id ....";
 var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

 var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 12, 2015 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("January 18, 2017 23:59:59 CST"))

 for (var i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

      var myStart = events[i].getStartTime();
      var myTitle = events[i].getTitle();
      var myDesc = events[i].getDescription();
      var myTalkNo = ??

 }
```

How do I query the private extended property named "talk-number" on each event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Google Apps Script you have two ways to interact with Google Calendar; the [Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) and the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) (aka Calendar API) which must be enabled via Advanced Google Services.

The ACS uses the resource representations from the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/), so the `extendedProperties` are available as a part of the event objects you can obtain through the API.

Here's a simple modification of the example from the ACS docs that will log the "talk-number" for every event that has one.

```
function listNext10Events() {
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var now = new Date();
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
    timeMin: now.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    maxResults: 10
  });
  if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
      var event = events.items[i];
      if (event.start.date) {
        // All-day event.
        var start = parseDate(event.start.date);
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, start.toLocaleDateString());
      } else {
        var start = parseDate(event.start.dateTime);
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, start.toLocaleString());
      }
      /********************************************************************/
      if (event.hasOwnProperty("talk-number"))
        Logger.log(event.extendedProperties.private["talk-number"]);
      /********************************************************************/
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No events found.');
  }
}
```

You can update your function with this:

```
var eventId = events[i].getId().replace(/@.*/,'');  // Remove @google.com from eventId
var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId)
myTalkNo = event.extendedProperties.private["talk-number"];
```